# Remove element (x,y) from list of lists in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I need a predicate that given a list of lists (matrix)

```
removeElementM(Line,Column,List,NewList)
```

removes the (Line,Column) element.

For example given the List(L):

```
    ([a,b,c,d],
     [e,r,t,y],
     [u,i,o,t])

removeElementM(2,2,L,X) would return

X = [[a,b,c,d],[e,r,t,y],[u,i,t]]
```

I already have the stopping predicate

```
removeElementM(0,0,[[_|T1]|T],[T1|T]).
```

but cant't come up with the solution for the other one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that :

```
removeElementM(Line,Column,[List | Rest],[List |NewList]) :-
    Line > 0,
    Line1 is Line - 1,
    removeElementM(Line1, Column, Rest, NewList).

removeElementM(0, Column,[List | Rest],[List1 |Rest]) :-
    removeElementL(Column, List, List1).

removeElementL(Column, [H | T], [H | T1]) :-
    Column > 0,
    Column1 is Column - 1,
    removeElementL(Column1, T, T1).

removeElementL(0, [_H | T], T).
```

Comment: works like a charm, thank you! I just began learning prolog so this is the type of answer I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[nth0](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth0/4)/4 as implemented in SWI-Prolog is rather powerful. You need to replace a row with another where the element has been deleted. Then

```
removeElementM(R, C, Mat, Upd) :-
    nth0(R, Mat, OldRow, RestRows),   % get the row and the rest
    nth0(C, OldRow, _Val, NewRow),    % we don't care the _Val deleted
    nth0(R, Upd, NewRow, RestRows).   % insert updated row in rest, get Upd matrix

test :-
    L = [[a,b,c,d],
         [e,r,t,y],
         [u,i,o,t]],
    removeElementM(2,2,L,X),
    writeln(X).

?- test.
[[a,b,c,d],[e,r,t,y],[u,i,t]]
```

If you are learning Prolog, you are better to verify the answer from @joel76, it's basic Prolog without SWI-Prolog specific features.

Comment: It does the trick thank you, I will keep this solution even though as you said I just began in prolog so joel76's answer would be best suited for me to understand. Thanks again